# Ionic Implement List Section Index Titles With Scroll Effects Like iOS UITableView

Tags: ionic-framework

I know for iOS there is native way to implement Section Index Titles Scroll Effects like Apple Phone Contacts. The effects are marked in the following pics with colors. When scrolling, Header `B` will push Header `A`, and Header `B` then will fix at the top of the scroll view.

Anyone know how to implement it using `IONIC` ? I did find a similar [ionic plugin](http://codepen.io/Poordeveloper/pen/BNpxrm), but the effects of 'pushing header' is different.

[image]
[image]